# Parsing CDATA in xml with python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, lxml

I need to parse an XML file with a number of blocks of CDATA that I need to retain for later plotting:

`<process id="process1"> 
  <log name="name1" device="device1"><![CDATA[timestamp value]]]></log>
 <log name="name2" device="device2"><![CDATA[timestamp value, timestamp value, timestamp]]]></log>
</process>`

I will need to do this repeatedly and quickly, and I am looking for the best way to do this.  I've read that ElementTree is the faster of the methods, but I am open to other suggestions.

Comment: xtree is another alternate for your problem better than element tree.

Answer (score 16):

Here are two examples of how to do it:

```
from lxml import etree
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ElementTree

CONTENT = """
<process id="process1">
 <log name="name1" device="device1"><![CDATA[timestamp value]]></log>
 <log name="name2" device="device2"><![CDATA[timestamp value, timestamp value, timestamp]]></log>
</process>
"""

def parse_with_lxml():
    root = etree.fromstring(CONTENT)
    for log in root.xpath("//log"):
        print log.text

def parse_with_stdlib():
    root = ElementTree.fromstring(CONTENT)
    for log in root.iter('log'):
        print log.text

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parse_with_lxml()
    parse_with_stdlib()
```

Output:

```
timestamp value
timestamp value, timestamp value, timestamp
timestamp value
timestamp value, timestamp value, timestamp
```

The text attribute it handles it in both cases.

Comment: For performance, `cElementTree` could be used (note: leadind `c`)