# How to get string between two delimiters python

Tags: python

I have entries like the following:

```
"<![CDATA[Lorem ipsum feed for an interval of 30 seconds]]>"
```

How do I get the string between the innermost square brackets i.e. 'Lorem ipsum feed for an interval of 30 seconds'

Where some of the entries are plain strings and some are delimited by [] as above

Comment: Best to show one of each of the possible options in your post

Comment: Can there be anything before or after the `<![CDATA[....]]>`? If not, you might just use a slice `[9:-3]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find the string between two special characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14716342/how-do-i-find-the-string-between-two-special-characters)

Comment: Looks like your data is valid XML, so use a XML parser. Regular expressions will not cover some corner cases.

Comment: Use ElementTree to parse it

Comment: "I have **entries** like...", so what's the actual data like? Is it XML? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13694143/parsing-cdata-in-xml-with-python

Comment: @IljaEverilä it's supposed to be html but some of the pages are xml, the html pages return a string title the xml pages return the above

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `split()` method of `str`. See the below code snippet:

```
 string = "<![CDATA[[[[[Lorem ipsum feed for an interval of 30 seconds]]]]]]]>"
 inner_str = string.split('[')[len(string.split('[')) -1 ].split(']')[0]
 print inner_str
```

Comment: Nice! Just the second line can be written in a better way:`inner_str = string.split('[')[-1].split(']')[0]`

Answer (score 2):

You can use what is mentioned in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14716342/how-do-i-find-the-string-between-two-special-characters), except in order to get the inner most strings, you will have to recursively call that.

Modifying the accepted answer, you can achieve it using the following:

```
def find_inner(s):
    temp = s.partition('[')[-1].rpartition(']')[0]
    if not temp:
        return s

    return find_inner(temp)
```

Comment: I believe this will not cover some corner cases from OP's use case, for example, the data can contain unbalanced brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expressions:

```
import re
string = '<![CDATA[Lorem ipsum feed for an interval of 30 seconds]]>'
reverse = string[::-1]
start = len(string)-re.search(r'\[', reverse).start()
end = re.search(r'\]', string).start()
print(string[start:end])
```

You should find the text between the last `[` and the first `]`. In the above code, I use the `re.search()` function to find the first occurrence of a character. It is ok for finding the first occurrence of `]`. But to find the last occurrence of `[`, I reverse the string and find the first occurrence of it (the position is subtracted from `len(string)` since it is indexed backward).