# BeautifulSoup html.parser and <link> tag in xml (vs CDATA with 'lxml' parser). Must I use both?

Tags: python, html, xml, parsing, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse with BeautifulSoup html.parser, and I am having trouble with the  tag, in that it is being processed differently than other tags:

On the `<title>` tag, it works as expected:

```
>>> BeautifulSoup("<title>Somalia’s Electoral Crisis in Extremis</title>", features='html.parser')
<title>Somalia’s Electoral Crisis in Extremis</title>
```

However when processing the `<link>` tag, it introduces a slash in the opening tag and drops the closing tag:

```
>>>BeautifulSoup("<link>https://warontherocks.com/2021/04/somalias-electoral-crisis-in-extremis/</link>", features='html.parser')
<link/>https://warontherocks.com/2021/04/somalias-electoral-crisis-in-extremis/
```

Why is it doing this?

Now if I use the `'lxml'` or `'xml'` tags, it works fine.

```
>>> BeautifulSoup("<link>https://warontherocks.com/2021/04/somalias-electoral-crisis-in-extremis/</link>", features='lxml')
<html><head><link/></head><body><p>https://warontherocks.com/2021/04/somalias-electoral-crisis-in-extremis/</p></body></html>
```

I am using `html.parser` because I also encounter nested elements (tags like `<something:tag>`) and `CDATA` strings. So parsing CDATA with `lxml` (which did not work for me) would also be a solution if it is possible.

Am I going to have to write some logic to decide which library to parse each site with, or is there a way to do this with BeautifulSoup as is?

Comment: lxml is faster and more forgiving so I generally use that. There is an existing post comparing the various parsers as well as in the documentation. Link should have no end tag: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-link-element. I assume lxml is attempting a repair on this html?

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to handle CDATA in `lxml`? That is why I am not using it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13694143/parsing-cdata-in-xml-with-python.  ![CDATA[]] is an  instruction that content should not be interpreted as xml. There are probably more answers on how to work with CDATA. I will have a quick look. This is just the one that came to mind. I note you wanted to use lxml.

Comment: Or is there a way to specify custom tags for cases where I encounter ones that are malformed in a specific way?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37661822/python-lxml-modify-cdata, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25813756/lxml-kills-my-cdata-sections ....and possibly from these: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=lxml+cdata